# GAE/Python ImportError timegm

Tags: python, eclipse, google-app-engine, calendar

I'm pretty new to both Python and Google App Engine and I'm slowly going nuts trying to resolve the following compile error.

> File "/opt/google/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py",
>   line 26, in 
>       import cookielib   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/cookielib.py", line 38, in 
>       from calendar import timegm
>       ImportError: cannot import name timegm

I'm using the PyDev plugin in Eclipse to deploy locally.  As far as I can see there is no reason for the error.  I've tried adding the timegm.py folder to the PYTHONPATH configuration, and I've even proved the point by simply importing `from calendar import timegm` using auto complete in my code!

I've seen others with the problem but no solutions.  Anyone know how to fix this?

Code follows:

```
import httplib2
import webapp2
from apiclient.discovery import build
from google.appengine.api import oauth
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):    
    def get(self):
        flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(__CLIENT_ID, __CLIENT_SECRET, _SCOPE, _REDIRECT_URI)
    authUri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()            
    queryString = parse_qs(urlparse(authUri).query)

    if 'error' not in queryString:
        # Create an httplib2.Http object to handle our HTTP requests and authorize it
        credentials = flow.step2_exchange(queryString['code'])
        http = httplib2.Http()  
        http = credentials.authorize(http)            
        service = build("calendar", "v3", http=http)                                                
        events = service.events().list(calendarId=__VISITORS_CALENDAR).execute(http=http)

        if events['items']:
            # show what we've got
            for event in events['items']:
                self.response.write(event['summary'])
        else:
            self.response.write('No events found in the calendar')

    else:
        self.response.write('Denied...')


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug = True)
```

Comment: PS: the indenting is screwed up in my post, but it's fine in the file

Comment: just adding stuff to python path is insufficient, you have to copy any 3rd party lib into your project and directly manipulate sys.path.  This is a question that has been asked and answered over and over again.  How about searching SO first.

Comment: I didn't bother to include the link to the same question there are so many duplicates ;-)

Comment: @TimHoffman It does that automatically when trying to close the question..

Comment: Guys, these comments/downvotes are unfair: `timegm` is a function in the built-in `calendar` module, he shouldn't have to install anything.

Comment: What does this have to do with third-party? Looks like the problem is a `from calendar import timegm` statement. `timegm` is a function in `calendar`, which is a std lib module. You shouldn't need to do anything with PYTHONPATH, sys.path, or anything like that. It seems that your Python installation is messed up somehow. Try reinstalling. Also, try running from cmd line instead of Eclipse. I promise it's not much harder than clicking around in Eclipse's UI.

Comment: If Daniel Roseman's answer doesn't do the trick, try a more basic app. It will help you isolate the problem.

Comment: I edited the question so we can retract the downvote :) soz

Comment: Hey all.  Actually the link from Lipis was correct and helped.  Though I had no idea that that was the source of the problem.  As allyourcode said - it's not 3rd party, so I would never have searched for that kind of thing (and believe me, I spent a looooong time searching calendar/timegm before posting).  Thanks for the support (and downvote retraction).

Answer (score 15):

There's no need to install anything, `calendar.timegm` is a function from the standard library.

What's probably happening is that you have a local file called `calendar.py`, which is hiding the stdlib version. Your calendar file doesn't have such a function, hence the error. Rename your file to something else.